# How to pass class with virtual methods around and how to use it as member variable?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, interface, smart-pointers

I've recently started unit testing my code, using Catch and Fakeit.
I have a wrapper class around the WinAPIs HWND.

```
class Window
{
public:
    Window(HWND hwnd);
    virtual void resize(int width, int height);
    ...
private:
    HWND m_hwnd;
};
```

This and the tests for it work fine. For the tests I'm creating some actual
windows using WinAPI's CreateWindow(...).

However, I've stumbled upon a problem and I'm not sure what's the best solution to it.
In my code I just kept passing Window by value, since it's basically just the HWND anyway.
Some methods take it as const&, but when using it as class members, I usually just copied it.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Window& window)
    : m_window(window)
    {}
private:
    Window m_window;
};
```

Now lets assume I want to test Foo. I need to somehow stub the Window class, but I can only do that
if I am able to override virtual methods. I think you see the problem here.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::shared_ptr<Window>& window)
    : m_window(window)
    {
        assert(m_window != nullptr);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Window> m_window;
};
```

I now spent the last two hours, refactoring all my code, so that I only pass std::shared_ptr and almost
never use the Window class by value. Foo now looks like this:
class
This makes sense, cause even if I pass the Window by value, it usually IS shared
anyway (if I resize it, it's resized for all instances).
However, I also felt that it complicated my code ALOT. For the comparison operator== I now always have to derefence
both sides. When I'm trying to find in an stl container, I now have to use

```
std::find_if(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(),[&needle](const SharedWindowPtr& ptr) { return *ptr == *needle; });
```

In addition to that, there's overhead from the shared_ptr. I also run the risk of passing nullptrs, where I want to ensure that doesn't happen. I can check that with assertions, but that isn't foolproof. I could also not pass a shared_ptr but a reference to Foo's constructor and give the Window class a `std::unique_ptr<Window> clone()` method, but I would have to mock that for every test and if there's a way around it I'd prefer that.

Now I'm wondering if there's any better/cleaner method for handling this kind of problem? Thanks for any advice on this.

EDIT: After thinking about this for a while, I had another idea to approach this.

```
class WindowHandler
{
public:
    virtual void resize(int w, int h) = 0;
    virtual void getTitle() = 0;
    // ...
};

class DefaultWindowHandler
{
public:
    DefaultWindowHandler(HWND hwnd);
    virtual void resize(int w, int h) override
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
protected:
    HWND m_hwnd;
};

class Window
{
public:
    Window(HWND hwnd)
    : m_windowHandler(new DefaultWindowHandler(hwnd))
    {
        // empty
    }
    void setWindowHandler(WindowHandler* handler)
    {
        assert(handler != nullptr);
        m_windowHandler.reset(handler);
    }
    void resize(int w, int h)
    {
        m_windowHandler->resize(w, h);
    }
};
```

What I like about this, is that I can pass the Window class around by value and still get the benefits of the interface-like behaviour if I need to. What do you think about that, what are the shortcomings? I know that the Window should probably accept a WindowHandler instead of the HWND as the constructor argument, but it's just easier to use the way it is.

Comment: A simple reference or a non owning raw pointer is okay, as long as `Foo` is not the owner of `Window`. If you need `Foo` to be the owner, you can use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I know that I can use unique_ptr of course, but that doesn't simplify anything, if all it makes it more complicated. I also know that I could use raw pointers, but in most cases I don't have a specific owner, but the window is manipulated from multiple places. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the class hierarchy involved here? Or is it just that one class? Are there lots of other member functions?

Answer (score 1):

Following what as been asked in the comment, it seems like `std::unique_ptr` will suffer from this option too. If taking by value of the base class, using any pointer or reference is not available, you can always use templates:

```
template<typename WindowType>
struct Foo {
    // Want speed? take by value!
    Foo(WindowType window)
    : m_window(std::move(window))
    {}

private:
    WindowType m_window;
};
```

Then, your class will work with all subtypes of window. But then, using template, the functions being virtual or not is irrelevant.

If you want to limit your class `Foo` to only accept subtypes of windows, you have two choices: sfinae-like or static_assert

**sfinae-like**

```
template<typename, typename = void>
struct Foo;

template<typename WindowType>
struct Foo<WindowType, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Window, WindowType>::value>> {
    Foo(WindowType window)
    : m_window(std::move(window))
    {}

private:
    WindowType m_window;
};
```

**static_assert**

```
template<typename WindowType>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Window, WindowType>::value, "WindowType must be a subclass of Window");

    Foo(WindowType window)
    : m_window(std::move(window))
    {}

private:
    WindowType m_window;
};
```

The sfinae-like method will have the advantage of being able to "overload" your class for other types that matches with other conditions, but the static_assert is slightly easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks alot. I've taken some time to rethink this now. I didn't even think about templates for this. However this wouldn't work with fakeit (which was the main reason for switching to an interface-like approach) and I would have to subclass for every test instead. I'll add another though I had to the main post.